# Typescript: Required callback parameters?

Tags: typescript

I want to define a function which takes a callback as a parameter, and that callback's parameters should be required. Typescript correctly reports a callback with a mismatched parameter type but says nothing about callbacks with no expected arguments.

Why does the second `on` call not error, and is there any way to make it error?

```
function on(callback: (num: number) => void) {
    callback(5);
}

on((string:bob) => { // typescript error
    console.log("What");
});

on(() => { // no typescript error?
    console.log("What");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way to do this.

Callbacks with fewer parameters than the caller provides are *extremely* common in JavaScript - functions like `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, etc all provide 3 or more arguments but are frequently given 1-parameter functions as callbacks.

Comment: Right, but I figured Typescript would provide a way to define callbacks with required params. Something like `function doThing(callback: (num!: number)...` would be cool, as opposed to the `?` optional parameter identifier.

Comment: But what would be the sense of adding a callback parameter if you don't want to use that parameter in the callback's body?

Comment: It may be common in Javascript, but it's also a common source of bugs. I expected that Typescript would provide a way to enforce parameters in a callback... Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: There isn't a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could define a type for the handler. Now you can only pass a callback that has a string argument.

```
// define a handler so you can use it for callbacks
type Handler = (t: string) => void;

function doSomething(t: string): void {
    console.log("hello " + t)
}

function thisFirst(callback: Handler) {
  callback('world') // ok
  callback(4) // not assignable to type 'string'
}

thisFirst(doSomething)
```

Comment: This does not address what the OP is asking.  With the code you show it would be possible to have `thisFirst(() => console.log("foo"));` compile without error. The OP wants that code to give an error because the callback does not have an argument defined on it.

Comment: Yeah good point. My solution would be not to use anonymous callbacks at all but just define a type and a function name. In my opinion that results in cleaner, more readable code but I realise that's just my opinion :-)

Comment: Anonymous or not is not a factor in the problem here. Take the code you show in your answer, and define `doSomething` like this: `function doSomething(): void {`. And remove the reference to `t` in from `doSomething`. You can still do `thisFirst(doSomething)` without getting a compilation error on that call.

Comment: True! But how do we solve this then? Why can't we enforce parameters on a callback function?