# Typescript compiler is not working right?

Tags: typescript, function, callback, higher-order-functions

I am trying to understand function types in typescript. I wrote the code below its suppose to throw an error but its not working right.

```
function display():void{
     console.log("Function is a type")
}

function displayName(name:string):void{
     console.log("This is my "+name)
}

function returnName(name:string):string{
     return "My name is "+ name
}

let thatsMyName:(naem:string)=>void;
thatsMyName = display
```

As you can see i created three functions. I created a variable called thatsMyName and gave it type signature of returnName function but its storing any function i gave it. Its suppose to throw error at compile time but its not throwing. Can someone point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Required callback parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924625/typescript-required-callback-parameters)

Comment: It is perfectly valid in javascript/typescript. If you pass more parameters than the functions expect - nothing bad will happen. It will just ignore the additional parameter. More info on type compatibility https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thoughts:**

Regarding to the comment of Amadan, I try to explain my understanding of [the above commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924625/typescript-required-callback-parameters) answer. I do not think it's 100% of a duplicate but the answer and the focus of the question is kind of the same. (If you want to mark this question as duplicate - feel free to do so).

**Answer:**

The seen behavior from your side seems to be caused through the fact that every JavaScript-Code is valid TypeScript code. That as prerequisite explainst the following szenario:

As in the linked question answered: Many extremely common JavaScript-Functions have callbacks with 3 or more parameters. For example [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) has a callback that can be used with (currentValue, index, array). The common pitfall is to use it only with currentValue. So the callback amount/content of parameteres are not equal.

From TypeScript side what does it mean: Every JavaScript Function with callbacks needs to be optional and not strongly typed. Otherwise all JavaScript code, would not execute under the hood of TypeScript.

**Further Info:**

The output of your function (=> void | string) is strongly typed.