# Calling a function with fewer parameters than it provides

Tags: typescript

```js
let z:(s:string)=>void = () => alert("HI");
z("HI")
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAXgXAFAZxgsAnAlgOwOYEoC8AfAG4D26AJhPhHLtYRAIaiphwBEAEgJIe4BuALAAoKJ178gA)

Could someone help me understand why the above code compiles ?

I expected the compiler to complain about a type mismatch error in line 1, since I am assigning `() => void` and the specified type is `(s:string) => void`, but the program compiles without any errors.

Comment: Why would it be an error? That function _does_ accept a single string argument, it just _ignores_ it. And any return type matches void, which just means "callers don't care what it returns".

Comment: See the TS FAQ entry [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) If that fully addresses the question I can write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz if it's in the FAQ do you _need_ to write up yet another answer? Close as dupe, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45924625/3001761, this comes up all the time.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for that link. The FAQ answered my questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think this should closed as dupe, as the link you posted does not contain an explanation on why functions can be called with fewer parameter ("Substitutability") than the caller provides.